# View does not fit to ipad retina in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ipad-mini

When I run my app in Simulators it works, but when I test it with real device the view is not filling the view.

In the simulators & ipad mini 8.4 :

```
NSLog(@"frame Main %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
 frame Main {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}
```

In this screen is correctly working ,the bottom view(grey color) is showing
& Screen Shot is:
[image]

On ipad non Retina (10 inch ipad  6.3)

```
NSLog(@"frame Main %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
 frame Main {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
```

In this screen is not working correctly,the bottom view(grey color) is not showing i'm getting the space under Navigation bar also

[image]

What am I doing wrong...

Comment: what do you mean? Is it visually not filling the screen or are you expecting more pixels reported?

Comment: yes view is moved below,by the Version any problem come like tis?

Answer (score 1):

Try below process. Hope so it will work.

1. You have to added Autoresizing for the specific view. look at the screen shot.
   [image]
2. If in case in your application in Autolayout enable so that you have add left, right, top and bottom constraints.

Note : Add Launch images source for iPad

Comment: no this is not my problem, my view fully changed it move below in ipad retina